# Absolute path of the project root directory in Julia

Tags: julia

The project root directory of a file located in `PROJECT_ROOT/lib/code.jl` can be accessed with this code:

```
root = dirname(dirname(@__FILE__))
```

Using `dirname()` twice seems pretty ugly.  Is there a better way to do this?  With Ruby, I would use this code:

```
root = File.expand_path('../', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for making me find out about:

```
"/"*relpath((@__FILE__)*"/../..","/")
```

According to `?relpath`, it gives a path from the location of the second argument in the file-system, to the first argument. Is this better than the double `dirname` solution?

A variant of the same niceness is:

```
normpath(joinpath(@__FILE__,"..",".."))
```

Closest to Ruby equivalent might be:

```
realpath(dirname(@__FILE__)*"/..")
```

Comment: To make it OS agnostic, it would have to be `Base.path_separator*relpath(@__FILE__*"/../..",Base.path_separator)`. Ugh.

Comment: The `normpath` version seems to me the stablest/cleanest.

Comment: I can't get the first solution to work `"/"*relpath(@__FILE__*"/../..","/")`.  The other solutions work perfectly :)

Comment: Weird, seems like a parsing problem. Surrounding the `@__FILE__` by parenthesis solves it. `relpath((@__FILE__)*"/../..","/"))`

Answer (score 2):

I like to use

```
module Foo

const PROJECT_ROOT = pkgdir(Foo)

end # module
```

where the definition of `PROJECT_ROOT` can also be replaced by

```
const PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(dirname(pathof(Foo)))
```

Or, you could use

```
const PROJECT_ROOT = pkdir(@__MODULE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Base.active_project()
# c:\path\to\Project.toml
```

will give you the Project.toml path of your current active project.

To activate the project in your current directory you can run

```
pkg> activate .
```

in the Julia package manager

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Julia package for this task exactly: https://github.com/jolars/ProjectRoot.jl

To create a file path relative to the project root, you just need to call

```
using ProjectRoot

@projectroot("plots", "some_figure.png")
```

to for instance retrieve a path to a figure in `plots/some_figure.png`

Answer (score -1):

I just use

```
const PROJECT_ROOT = @__DIR__
```

from inside my `_init.jl` file, which resides in the project root directory (next to the `src` directory) and gives you a canonical path.

I get my `_init.jl` files automatically executed when opening a Julia session from inside that directories by having

```
isfile("_init.jl") && include(joinpath(pwd(), "_init.jl"))
```

in my `~/.julia/config/startup.jl` file. If you started Julia elsewhere, you have to `include("_init.jl")` it (or respective relative path) manually.